# API to authenticate credentials in apigee

Tags: apigee

I was wondering on if there was an api in apigee edge which I could call to authenticate apigee edge user credentials .

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand correctly... perhaps you mean client credentials? Or do you mean user credentials that are stored in API BAAS or another user authentication system?

Comment: User credentials  ( users who are allowed to log into the edge system)

Answer (score 0):

We're sorry, Edge user credential authentication is not available.  Please contact Apigee directly if you have related concerns, and we'd be happy to discuss further.